# How can I add flooring to an attic floor with electrical wires running across it?

Tags: floor, attic

Want to floor attic space that has electrical wires tacked to joists.  is the best way to notch out additional boards over wires and add to the top of these joists and then floor?

Comment: The first step, is to make sure the joists are strong enough to support a floor. It's often the case that attics are not designed to have a floor.

Comment: @Tester101: Good point. My place would have needed the joists sistered, and other work done, before the attic could be turned into usable space... so I decided it was nothing but a roof and blew in a deep bed of insulation.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely consider the first couple of comments regarding whether the joists are even strong enough to support a floor.

Presuming the joists are strong enough, you could probably run firring strips on top of the existing joists, these could be 2x4's on their sides, or you could rip them down to 2x2's. You would either notch them or just cut them and leave a gap every place a wire crosses the original joist. You would *have* to put metal plates across the gaps to protect the wires. There just isn't enough depth otherwise and you'll drive screws or nails through the wire when you install the flooring.

[image]

Alternatively, you may consider running new "joists" (check around with some builders, but even 2x4's might be sufficient if you're on 16" centers?) ACROSS the existing joists, perpendicular to them, rather than directly on top of them in the same direction. You can probably reduce the number of notches you need to cut for the wiring this way, and it would also raise the new floor high enough over the wires that you don't need to put a steel plate over each wire.

It would be pretty easy to secure these "cross joists," especially if you run them clear over the tops of the end walls.

If your original joists aren't strong enough to support a floor, you could either sister the joists, or possibly place new joists on top of them that *are* strong enough and are supported on the load-bearing end walls. But if you go there, you want to get a builder or engineer/architect involved if you don't have the background to design it yourself.

There might be something in the N.E.C. about a minimum distance for the wiring under the flooring, as well, despite the use of the metal plates at the points where they cross.

What's to keep somebody (even a kid) from driving a nail or screw into the floor at some future date and drive it through the wire?

You might consider laying sheet metal strips down the entire length of all of these cables.

The N.E.C. does say that cables stapled across the tops of joists the way you describe have to be protected with boards running alongside the cables (so someone stepping on the cable doesn't damage it--the board helps keep the weight off the cable).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Craig pretty much covered it...running boards with wires nestled down inside the cavity they create.  If these running boards are positioned off to the side of your new flooring area and your'e not throwing plywood over them, then you don't necessarily need a 'top protective cover' over the wires.

However, if the wires can't be moved to be placed inside this trough, then you would need to make some type of protective cover of metal which would forbid any screws from accidentally being screwed into the wire when installing plywood flooring.  So definitely a metal strip made of a guage thickness that would forbid screws from going through.

Remember this, its not so much that you are attempting to arrange the wires for what it is that you are doing, as it is for all those that come behind you in the years to come. You might know where all the wires are so that you don't run a screw through them....BUT! if they aren't buried underneath the flooring and protected accordingly, some homeowner in the future may come along and screw that 'buckling plywood' down with a 3" screw and send that baby right down in the middle of some romex wiring.

Or, if you run the wires through the joists perpendicular and alongside a joist, make certain you have the wire in the center of the board.  The code specifies 1.25" below surface of board face but this really applies to areas of a residence whereby sheetrock would be installed and not for attic flooring.  I would keep the wires centered in the joists at all times and use the nail plates (as shown above by other poster) over every single wire that goes through a joist member.  Once again, not so much to protect you although it is, but more so to prevent the before-mentioned from occuring.